# I try to align text next to checkbox but checkbox appear too small

Tags: html, css

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

#termAndCondtion {
  position: absolute;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div><input type="checkbox" id="termAndCondtion" name="agree"></div>
  <div>اقر ان الرغبات التي تقدمت بها هي الرغبات الصحيحة وتم التأكد منها والبيانات التي تقدمت بها هي البيانات الصحيحة</div>
</div>
```

like it's appear in pic
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tgjp.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flexbox` here and add

```
display: flex;
```

on parent `.wrapper` element

```css
.wrapper{
display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div><input type="checkbox" id="termAndCondtion" name="agree"></div>
  <div>اقر ان الرغبات التي تقدمت بها هي الرغبات الصحيحة وتم التأكد منها والبيانات التي تقدمت بها هي البيانات الصحيحة</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do u want that text content right beside the checkbox?
If so then use the below code. I hope I am helpful.

```css
div {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    
    #termAndCondtion {
      position:absolute;
      float: right;
    }
}
```

```html
  <div><input type="checkbox" id="termAndCondtion" name="agree">اقر ان الرغبات التي تقدمت بها هي الرغبات الصحيحة وتم التأكد منها والبيانات التي تقدمت بها هي البيانات الصحيحة</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <input type="checkbox" id="termAndCondtion" name="agree">
  <label for="termAndCondtion">اقر ان الرغبات التي تقدمت بها هي الرغبات الصحيحة وتم التأكد منها والبيانات التي تقدمت بها هي البيانات الصحيحة</label>
</div>
```

## Placing checkbox and sentence in the same line

You do not require any external CSS to achieve this. You can just use the `<label>` tag which also enhances the accessibility for users of small screens. Also, the text shifting to next line will be because you are wrapping the checkbox inside a `<div>` tag which is styled as `display: block;` by default.

## Placing checkbox to the right

You can place both the elements inside a `flexbox` and give it a `flex-direction: row-reverse;` to make the sentence come before the checkbox.

*Note: You can also place the checkbox before the sentence manually in the `<div>` with HTML but it is a good practice to change the looks of a page using CSS only since you might want to keep the checkbox on the left when the language is of left-right written type or for any other use-case or if the resource loading runs into an error and fails to load the CSS file.*

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CSS direction right to left for arabic, and to have the checkbox appear next to it.
In order to have them both in the same line, converting the `div` to a `span` would work, but the text make continue under the checkbox which you probably don't want, so in this case, using flexbox model is better.

You should learn more about it from [w3Schools flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

```css
.arabic-text {
    direction: rtl;
}

.d-flex {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="arabic-text d-flex">
  <div>
       <input type="checkbox" id="termAndCondtion" name="agree">
  </div>
  <div>اقر ان الرغبات التي تقدمت بها هي الرغبات الصحيحة وتم التأكد منها والبيانات التي تقدمت بها هي البيانات الصحيحة</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use input and label elements together as a best practice.

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="TC" name="agree">
<label for="agree"> ..your text.. </label>
```

This would automatically place the text next to the checkbox since its an inline element

To change the size of the checkbox, you could use height and width properties. If you needed, vertical-align could also be added.

```css
#TC {
  height: 1.3rem;
  width: 1.3rem;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="TC" name="agree">
<lable for="agree"> ..your text.. </lable>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.adjustment{
        float: right
}
.text {
    text-alight:right
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="adjustment"><input type="checkbox" id="termAndCondtion" name="agree"></div>
  <div class="text">اقر ان الرغبات التي تقدمت بها هي الرغبات الصحيحة وتم التأكد منها والبيانات التي تقدمت بها هي البيانات الصحيحة</div>
  </div>
</body>
```